# How to avoid SQL injection in a javascript text field?

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-injection

I have a javascript code that access a sqlite3 database. I would like to validate my text field value and prevent SQL injection. Is there an "optimum algorithm" for that?

**--update:** I'm developing a Xulrunner desktop application. Maybe I should use the database in the xpcom component, which is compiled (written in C), so the user will not have access to it..

Comment: Presumably the Javascript is not accessing the database directly, as Javascript is normally found on the client side.  What are you running on your server?

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913837/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-using-javascript-or-c

Comment: Your javascript code is directly accessing the db?

Comment: @standau ops, sorry, it really answers the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically SQL injection is avoided using parameterized SQL statements.

Here's an [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) article describing how you would do this.

Here is another [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) that describes several ways you can prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 6):

SQL injection prevention is done at the server side, there is nothing you can do on the client side to prevent it.

Comment: Yes, but he's using sqlite3, which I would assume is local rather than on a server.

Comment: @Gordon Worley, in this context I would say server side would be inclusive of some form of language like PHP, C#, etc. that cannot be disabled/modified by end user.

Comment: @Gordon Worley -You mean he is accessing a database that resides on the client side? Man, that's a concept. Never thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what type of environment you're in, but be aware that because of the nature of JavaScript and the way it's often executed in browsers, etc., code injection attacks are relatively easy, so any validation you do on the client side could be side stepped by anyone who is serious about an attack.  Not that you shouldn't validate, just that you should be aware that you need to pay attention to where you're running to know if validation is enough.